# Android Face detection of a static image using opencv?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I found out opencv sample face detection example for android but it is detecting face from a video stream. I want to detect face of a static image from image gallery. So far i am able to retrieve image using image gallery. But i am not able tweak the opencv example. I do not want to use the FaceDetection api which is available in SDK. 
Any help greatly appreciated! Thank You.

Comment: can you overwrite the methods in OpenCV class? You just have to override image() method which returns the same image.

Comment: Make some small modification on face detection example to work with static images.

Comment: there are many functions wrt video streamin, i find it hard to modify those.!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect faces from static images, you could try to use an algorithm such as SURF:
http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

code: http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/features2D/SURF_Homography.cpp

The example detects an object in an static image.